# My character becomes small when moving

Tags: game-maker

When I move, my character becomes small, I don't know why though. Here is my code: the first one is to go right, and the second one is for going left.

[image: this is for the character to go right]

[image: This is for my character to go left]

Comment: Can you can how it looks like and how it should look like?

Comment: What scale do you have on your player object to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

The *Set Instance Scale* blocks are setting the horizontal scale to `±2` and the vertical scale to `1`. You're scaling **twice** on the X-axis than on the Y-axis, then your sprite is stretched horizontally and the final effect is a squat character.

Just set the horizontal scale to `±1`, so that the sprite only gets flipped around. Otherwise, increase the vertical scale to `2` in both blocks, and the final result will be an object twice as big as the original sprite.